# Image attachment sends?? but doesnt apppear in email message Python smtp

Tags: python, smtp, attachment

I am trying to send screenshots along with an email message..

The message gets through fine.

In Windows Live mail it has the attachment icon. but no attachments are there.

Online in outlook it has no attachment..

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = client_name + "  eBay Template " + date
msg['From'] = sender_address
msg['To'] = recipients_address
msg.preamble = 'images'
```

...
    # attach screenshot

```
iways_filename = dictstr['ItemID'] + "_i-ways" + '.png'
ebay_filename = dictstr['ItemID'] + "_ebay" + '.png'
# iways
img_data = open(iways_filename, 'rb').read()
image = MIMEImage(img_data, name=os.path.basename(iways_filename))
msg.attach(image)
#ebay
img_data2 = open(ebay_filename, 'rb').read()
image = MIMEImage(img_data2, name=os.path.basename(ebay_filename))
msg.attach(image)
```

I get no errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution..

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = client_name + "  eBay Template " + date
msg['From'] = sender_address
msg['To'] = recipients_address
msg.preamble = 'images'
```

Take away the 'alternative' and Voila!

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = client_name + "  eBay Template " + date
msg['From'] = sender_address
msg['To'] = recipients_address
msg.preamble = 'images'
```